# Adjusting the width of the select drop button in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my code I am using bootstrap css for styling . I have written a code for a drop down menu with class form-control. The problem is that I cant adjust the width of the form. It is now like occupying the total width of the webpage like:

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|                                            Choose the option

I just need to adjust the size of the dropdown . I am totally new to this field . 
Somebody can help me out .?
I am attaching the part of code with this :

```
<body>    
    <select class="form control">
        <option value= "1">one</option>
        <option value= "2">two</option>
        <option value= "3">three</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

[bootstrap link](http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css)

Comment: attach the CSS as well ;)

Comment: i am using bootstrap css

Comment: Bootstrap by default has `width: 100%` in `form-control` elements, so you will have to override it. Also, assuming that your class is `form-control` instead of `form control`, because by default select elements are `inline-block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you are using Bootstrap, the class `.form-control` by default has the following properties:

```
.form-control {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

So, if you are using bootstrap you will have to override it using a custom class/id, or set a parent with a fixed width.

#### HTML

```
<div class="form-container">
    <select class="form control">
        <option value= "1">one</option>
        <option value= "2">two</option>
        <option value= "3">three</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.form-container{
    width: 30%; //or width: 200px, etc
}
```

Comment: @achu: don't forget to mark an answer as correct, you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Link your own stylesheet to the document...

Declare the class `form-control` in this document.. or add a new class to the html next to this, then add the height/width attributes:

Html:

```
<select class="form-control resizeformc">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
.resizeformc {
    width: 150px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the bootstrap grid system.  Adding a pre-defined responsive class like "col-xs-4" to your class list for the select element.  (note this will only cover your width requirement, but if all elements use the grid system is can help keep the form looking clean and well organized).

A helpful reference for the bootstrap grid system may be found here http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp